# Keras 'flow_from_directory' is Extremely Slow

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

I have an image classification project I'm working on that has 17,255 images and 49 categories.  This is a proof-of-concept exercise.  The actual end-product will involve somewhere between 100,000 and 500,000 images.  Given the large number of images and their size, I decided to look into the Keras 'flow_from_directory' functionality.

When I initially ran the code below against the entire image set it ran for over an hour without completing.  To bound the problem I created a subset of images and directory categories.  For a hundred or so images the script completed in around 30 seconds.

When I upped things to around 1,400 images the script took over 30 minutes to complete.  That would be 2,800 images per hour or over 6 hours for my dataset (feel free to check my math).  And that is just the data generation part, not including any actual training

I'm running on a Google instance with 8 CPUs and 50 Gig of RAM.  The CPU and memory usage when the script was running was minimal so hardware isn't the problem.

Machine specs:

```
instance-4 > uname -a
Linux instance-4 4.4.0-109-generic #132~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 21:46:42 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Python specs:

```
>>> print(keras.__version__)
2.1.2
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> print(tf.__version__)
1.4.1
>>> 
instance-4 > python -V
Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

The file store is Google Cloud.  The sample directory is:

```
instance-4 > ls -1 ./data/val
cat1
cat2
cat3
cat4
cat5
cat6
```

Within each directory/category are symbolic links to the actual image files (also on Google Cloud).

It occurred to me that the links could be the issue, but when I ran with a hundred or so image files the performance was about the same as with symbolic links (~ 30 sec)

**So my question is**: Am I doing something wrong or is the Keras 'flow_from_directory' just incapable of handling a large number of images (despite the advertising/documentation)?

Sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import warnings

#... Supress TensorFlow warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    import keras

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

from datetime import datetime
import time

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
validation_dir = './data/val'

start_time = time.time()
print( str(datetime.now()) )

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_dir,
        target_size=(100,100),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical',
        follow_links=True
)

print(validation_generator)

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.  I copied everything from Google Cloud to the disk on my instance and the generator runs is under 2 seconds for the entire image set.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I feel like this has the potential to be a common problem.

Comment: I did the same. I used colab, so i copied from my gdrive down to local host of that colab. The improvement is significant. But it is still not quite as good as I want it to be. I am thinking there may still significant disk I/O inefficiencies from .flow_from_dir(...)?